# Crosstab query to get results of three tables based on results table

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, ms-access-2016

This request might be asked many times but I have done a search last night to figure out but I came up with nothing.

I have three tables

Table A

| ID | City |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | LA |
| 2 | NY |
| 3 | LV |

Table B

| ID | Job |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | Programmer |
| 22 | Engineer |
| 33 | Database Administrator |
| 44 | Cyber Security Analyst |

Table C

| ID | Job level |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | Junior |
| 222 | Associate |
| 333 | Senior |
| 444 | Director |

Final table

| ID | EmployeeName | City_ID | Job_ID | Level_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | Susie | 1 | 11 | 333 |
| 1001 | Nora | 2 | 11 | 222 |
| 1002 | Jackie | 2 | 22 | 111 |
| 1003 | Mackey | 1 | 11 | 444 |
| 1004 | Noah | 1 | 11 | 111 |

I’d like to have a crosstab query using Microsoft Access that returns the following result ( based on city )

LA Table

| Jobs | Junior | Associate | Senior | Director |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Programmer | 1 | - | 1 | 1 |
| Engineer | - | - | - | - |
| Database Administrator | - | - | - | - |
| Cyber Security Analyst | - | - | - | - |

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for this is always:

1. Create a "base" query that joins the base tables and returns all data columns that you will need for the crosstab query.
2. Run the [crosstab query wizard](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8) using the "base" query as input.